# How can I take the contents of a C# class and put into / take out of a string?

Tags: c#

I have the following two classes:

```
public class TestQuestionModel
{
    public TestQuestionModel()
    {
        this.Answers = new List<TestQuestionAnswerModel>();
    }
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public int TestQuestionId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestQuestionAnswerModel> Answers { get; set; }

}

public class TestQuestionAnswerModel
{
    public int AnswerUId { get; set; }
    public bool? Correct { get; set; }
    public bool? Response { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

}
```

What I would like to do is to store the Answers into a string and put into this class:

```
public class TestQuestion
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public int TestQuestionId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionNumber { get; set; }
    public string AnswerString { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can do this in both directions (putting it in the string and taking it out)

Comment: You're looking for serialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible way:

```
    public string Serialize(ICollection<TestQuestionAnswerModel> answers)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(answers);
    }

    public ICollection<TestQuestionAnswerModel> Deserialize(string data)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return (ICollection<TestQuestionAnswerModel>)serializer.Deserialize<ICollection<TestQuestionAnswerModel>>(data);
    }
```